# Обрезается фоновая картинка, а должна растягиватся на всю ширину background-size: cover стоит

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Обрезается фоновая картинка, а должна растягиватся на всю ширину background-size: cover стоит
как исправить?
Отталкивает элемент вниз,у которого стоит position:absolute ,как сделать,чтоб не двигал?

```
<div class="leftImg"><img src="img/porcelaingirl.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="middleBlock">
                    <div class="topSection">
                        <h1>Art <br>Salon</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Оффициальный представитель,<br>
                    HAREND,LLADRO, и ROBBE&BERKING</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="rightImg"><img src="img/lowpoly_cat.png" alt=""></div>

.leftImg,
.rightImg
{
position: absolute;
left: 17%;
top: 25%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите минимальный воспроизводимы пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Изменил, теперь есть немного кода

Comment: Этого не достаточно. Сделайте фрагмент кода (иконка справа от вставки изображения в редакторе). Пример должен содержать html и css, достаточные, чтобы повторить проблему. В качестве изображений для наглядности можете использовать любые, найденные в поисковике, если не хотите/не имеете возможности вставить ссылку на оригинальные

Comment: Дико любопытно. при чем тут `background-size: cover`  и тег `<img>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у меня это было реализовано так:

```
function getSize(el) {
    var w = 0;
    var h = 0;
    if (el){
        w = el.offsetWidth;
        h = el.offsetHeight;
    }
    return {w, h};
}


const w = getSize(document.getElementById("*родительский элемент*")).w;
const h = getSize(document.getElementById("*родительский элемент*")).h;
```

.
.
.

```
<img src={img} height={h} width={w} alt=""/>
```